# data-target - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am displaying a `dialog` by using HTML directly

```
<!-- Dialog -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Something went wrong</h3>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Maximum 10 messages selected</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">RunIt</button>
```

but I would like to do something previously so I would like to execute  `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"` by javascript using `(click)`

So basically this would be the steps:

1- `(click)="test()"`

2- execute  `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"` by javascript in `test()`

to get the `DIV` that contains it, I have tried:

```
test(){
    var dialog= <HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById(exampleModalCenter);
  }
```

but I can not find the `exampleModalCenter`

Answer (score 1):

you should be using `attr.data-target`

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" 
        [attr.data-target]="'#exampleModalCenter">RunIt
</button>
```

Comment: No, no. My code in HTML is working but i need to do it by javascript to check some things before

Comment: @MarioLópez can you add the `javascript` code please

Comment: I just need to say if(x>10) show the dialog, if not, call to another method

Comment: you can add this condition inside your `click` method

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must add click method 'test' to button. Change your modal's class name as 'modal fade'. And after, your ts file must be like this:

```
@ViewChild('exampleModalCenter') exampleModalCenter;

test() {
  this.exampleModalCenter.nativeElement.className = 'modal fade show';
}
```

Comment: with @ViewChild  I can not find exampleModalCenter --> "@ViewChild('exampleModalCenter') exampleModalCenter;
"

Comment: Is your topmost div like this?  <div #exampleModalCenter class="modal fade">

Comment: Can you add '#exampleModalCenter' in your top div as i wrote ?